# ios opengles glsl textures

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

If I have 5 3D meshes in scene with 5 individual texture maps and 5 individual normal maps, do that means I have to bind all that 10 textures to Vertex Shader and Fragment Shader? If so, how do the real world practise to optimise this scenario?

Comment: Considering OpenGL ES 2.0 only guarantees 2 texture units, and you almost certainly do not need to do texture lookups in your vertex shader for this use-case, no. Use two samplers in your fragment shader, bind a normal map and diffuse map and draw all the objects that use that particular combination. Change the bound normal and diffuse maps and draw the rest, as many times as necessary. The only real way to optimize this scenario is to use texture atlases. If OpenGL ES 2.0 supported instancing, I would have another suggestion, but it does not :-\

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman don't mean to be rude but I don't quite understand your point. Say I have a human, a house, a car. Each of them have their own textures and normal maps. How do people manage this situation, which in gaming world, it is almost always this way.

Comment: Draw each object that has its own diffuse and normal map separately. In desktop OpenGL, which has instancing, the number of texture units can be divvied up and sometimes you can batch multiple objects with different texture maps into a single draw call. In GLES, however, you have to draw the objects, bind different textures, draw some more objects, bind different textures, etc.. You wind up having to issue at least one draw call per-set of texture maps, or you build texture atlases as I explained in the prior comment.